# Database design containing IP-Addresses and Network information

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mariadb, information-retrieval

I am new here and also a beginner to databases.
Right now I am working on a MariaDB database design for a small IP Address Management - Webapplication.
I tried to split redundant information into separate tables (e.g. `devicetypes`, `networks`, `buildings` and so on). Then I added relation from these separated tables to my main table `iptable`. 
Now I am wondering if you have any feedback or tricks on how to make it better?

[design so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpfYj.png)

thanks

Comment: you don't need `building_id` in both `switches` and `iptable` tables, i.e. you may consirer to remove it from one of them, most probably from `iptable`. Also `room` is redundant, so keep it only in one of these two tables.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - as it stands, your question is off topic.

Comment: Can't judge a schema without seeing the `SELECTs` that will be used on it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer function since this is too long for comments.

**Choose the right data types**

- ip has a defined display width of 255, while highest IP number can be represented as a 10 digit unsigned integer value.
- Mac address has always 17 chars, but is defined as
  VARCHAR(255) instead of fixed length CHAR(17)
- Are hostname and domain name related? Both hostname and domain name are defined as  VARCHAR(255). Max length of hostname is 63 characters, and max. length of fully qualified domain name is 255 characters.

**Avoid redundant information**

Storing redundant information not only takes up additional storage space, but also makes life harder when it comes to updating data.

E.g. `room` is defined in 2 different tables: If they are the same, remove one - if they are different, use different names (e.g. by prefixing the column name).